# Extract features from list using xpath Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I have been trying to get all the property information and features from this [URL](https://www.immoafrica.net/house-for-sale/camphersdrift/george/western-cape/za/IA0003812123/?r=71fe3b86-6764-4bb2-b454-130e89b6081e&i=0)

There is a list of them, however, when I try to get just one of them with my xpath I am unable to retrieve anything.

Here is what I have tried:

```
response.xpath('//div[@id="property-info-col1"]/text()').getall()
response.xpath('//div[@class="col-md-6"]').getall()
response.xpath('//*id[@class="property-info-col1"]').getall()
```

[image: Screenshot]
None of these seem to work, and I am not sure why.. Anyone has any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`/text()` will return *direct text children nodes*. In your case it is just empty strings. To get *string representation of `div`* try

```
'string(//div[@id="property-info-col1"])'
```

*UPDATE*

```
div = response.xpath('//div[@id="property-info-col1"]')
for dt, dd in zip(div.xpath('.//dt/text()'), div.xpath('.//dd/text()')):
    print(' - '.join([dt, dd]))
```

Comment: I get empty string as well. I would like to store each element separately, for instance, Price = R13,975,000', but I can't even access the whole class containing features. Is this what you suggested?
`response.xpath('string(//div[@id="property-info-col1"])').getall()`
@JaSON

Comment: @saraherceg try updated code. I don't familiar with Scrapy, so I'm not sure if it'll work. Let me know the result

Comment: the `div = response.xpath('//div[@id="property-info-col1"]')` still returns nothing, I am not sure why? @JaSON

Comment: @saraherceg. that's weird. check if you really get target HTML page. Server might not respond with correct page

Comment: It seems that it does get the good response, I will attach a screenshot of my shell in the question. @JaSON

Answer (score 0):

For your first xpath, because of the single slash, you are selecting only the text nodes that are immediate children of the `div`. This probably isn't what you expect, and what you want is all text nodes that are *descendants* of the `div`, not just children. Try using a double slash instead. `//div[@id="property-info-col1"]//text()`

Doing some testing in Python:

```
In [1]: from lxml import html

In [2]: f = open('travelpage.html', 'r')

In [3]: root = html.fromstring(f.read())

...

In [8]: root.xpath('//div[@id="property-info-col1"]/text()')
Out[8]: ['\n', '\n']

In [9]: root.xpath('//div[@id="property-info-col1"]//text()')
Out[9]: 
['\n',
 '\n',
 'Property Type',
 '\n',
 'House',
 '\n',
 'Listing Type',
 '\n',
 'For Sale',
 '\n',
 'Location',
 '\n',
 'Camphersdrift, George',
 '\n',
 'Price',
 '\n',
 '\nR 13,975,000\n· ',
 'Get Pre-Qualified',
 '\n',
 '\n',
 'Price per m²',
 '\n',
 'R 11,569',
 '\n',
 'Floor Size',
 '\n',
 '535 m²',
 '\n',
 'Erf Size',
 '\n',
 '1208 m²',
 '\n',
 '\n']
```

Comment: When I try to run the same command in scrapy shell I still get an empty list. How did you test this? Thank you for your help! @Forensic_07

Comment: This is an `ipython` shell, and I'm using `lxml` to parse a local text file of the web page's source that i saved to produce `root` and run an xpath on it. Here's the lxml docs: https://lxml.de/parsing.html#parsing-html. I'll update the code snippet to include the setup.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a double slash instead

```
response.xpath('//div[@id="property-info-col1"]//text()').getall()
```